# Issue with Jenkin integration with github private repo for auto SCM polling

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-github-plugin, jenkins-git-plugin

i have github + jenkin setup(for pipelining) which is working fine for public repos but as soon as i make my repo private, auto polling of my SCM breaks( basically after github webhook POST message back to jenkin to start the pipeline). In Github hook log i can see below error message. While i have updated my jenkin configuration to point to ssh github link with public/private key properly setup. I want to know why jenkin is picking up https link(as part of SCM polling) rather than ssh link which if picked will work. I have also tried passing PAT as part of repo name but it did not work either. Error - /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -- https://xxxxxx@github.com/xxxxxx/zzzzz.git # timeout=10
ERROR: polling failed in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/zzzzz on
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -- https://xxxxxx@github.com/xxxxxx/zzzzzzz" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.

I have already tried using ssh link with proper public/private key setup and it is working fine. I want to know why jenkin is picking up https link(as part of SCM polling) rather than ssh link which if picked will work. I have also tried passing PAT as part of repo name but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the project in Jenkins has been configured with a `https://` url for the private repo. As the error exception returned advises, GitHub no longer supports password authentication via `https://`.

Check the configuration of your project/pipeline, based on the fact that a ssh security key pair has been installed on Jenkins is using the ssh url:

1. In the project/pipeline configuration, locate the section for Source Code Management (`SCM`).
2. Check the repository URL to see if it is setup with the HTTPS URL, if so update to the SSH URL. It should look something like `git@github.com:xxxxxx/zzzzz.git`.
3. Save the configuration changes.